# Why is there a delay when I play a sound in Cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, ios-simulator

I am sure there is a way to do this, and I don't know how, and am new to sound in Cocos2d. I am using SimpleAudioEngine.h as directed to in Ray Wenderlich's wonderful tutorial (Part 1). The problem is, there is a delay when it plays a sound. I KNOW for a fact that there is a way to get rid of the delay, because, just look at all the games that are already out for iPhone!! Note that I am doing this on the Simulator, not on a real device, if that makes a difference. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, that does make a difference. If you don't test it on the device, how do you know the same effect will occur on the device? This goes for just about anything, graphic glitches, performance and what not. If you run into any technical issue with the Simulator, the first thing you'll have to get used to doing is to verify the problem also exists on the device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried preloadEffect? preload audio effects at initialize before calling playEffect:.

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadEffect:@"pew-pew-lei.caf"];
```

Comment: When are you calling preload? It should be in your app init code, and it only needs to be called once per sound effect.

Comment: For anyone reading this, you need to preload, then play it. Simply preloading the sound does not play it.

Comment: Also make sure that not only is the sound in your resources, but also added to your "copy bundle resources", because if it's not, it won't play. You can find this in project's target and click the "+" sign to add it.

Answer (score 0):

This fix might not work.  If the sound engine is not initialized properly, it will never preload properly.

Another possibility of sound stuttering: your code might be asking for multiple resource files at the same time, and if you are not multi-threading, it can affect the sound effects.

To test for this: comment out your code when the sound effects play.  If the sound effects do not stutter with your code commented out, that means your code is 'keeping the device or thread busy'.

I found this issue when I played an explosion animation.  When I commented out the animation code, the sound effect did not stutter the game play.